# Batch processing with Hibernate 4

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to have batch updates with hibernate. I have Hibernate integrated and i have added the property "hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" as 50. I was under the impression that batch updates will be done automatically after i add this property. However i do not see any such query where updates are being made in batch as i have show_sql property set to true.
 When i google it i find examples of how a batch can be flused with a loop and with flush and clear. 
But this doesnt make sense to me as it must be implemented in Hibernate and not something i need to implement. 
I want to know how to enable batch processing with Hibernate and how to verify.

**EDIT**

```
public void updateTasksInBatch(List<ScheduleTask> tasks) {


        for (ScheduleTask entity : tasks) {
            save(entity);
        }
    }
```

This method is on the service layer and is being called in the controller. The save method is as follows

```
public T save(T entity) throws EntityExistsException, 
                                    PersistenceException, 
                                    IllegalArgumentException, 
                                    TransactionRequiredException {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    }
```

Comment: `persist` is used to insert entities for the first time in db. you should use `merge` for update.

Comment: Ok, But even if its inserting it should be doing so in batch. Is that not true?

Comment: yes it should be

Comment: Well its not. I dont see anything such as "Executing batch size: X"

Comment: You will not see that, you will see a grouped insert. Check the blog I linked in the answer.

Comment: I do not see that as well. What i see are multiple update queries printed for the table it is inserting into

Comment: Btw i only see a query update without any parameters. ? is in place of the parameters and despite calling persist update query is being run.

Comment: Can't say without seeing the log

Answer (score 0):

The property `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` by default impacts `delete` and `insert` statements and doesn't batch `update` statements.

To enable `update` batching you need the property `hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data` set to `true`. But you should be carefull with this property, quoting [Vlad's blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/):

> Set this property to true if your JDBC driver returns correct row
>   counts from executeBatch(). It is usually safe to turn this option on.
>   Hibernate will then use batched DML for automatically versioned data.
>   Defaults to false.

Comment: I also have this property set . However what i am doing is there is a loop where an update method is being called and in that method .persist() is being called. Is that correct way?

Comment: Since you don't show the code I can't really say, the only thing is that the final statement should be update.

Comment: Can you tell what version of hibernate had implemented Batch update first? It seems like my version of Hibernate does not support batch updates